# df.isna().sum() not counting nan values

Tags: pandas, nan

I have several values in a Dataframe like this:
[image: ![enter image description here]

```
    Price_(zł)    Area_(m2) Rooms   Market      Building_type      Flat_level
0   1264850       62        3       secondary   apartment building  7
1   790000        80        4       secondary   block               0
2   606128        73,28     3       new         block               5
3   499000        70,50     4       secondary   nan                 nan
4   519000        40,86     2       new         block               5
5   508240        58,40     4       new         block               0
6   447568        50,86     3       new         block               0
7   Zapytajocenę  58,50     3       new         nan                 6
8   739375        84,50     4       new         apartment building  3
9   322400        52        3       new         nan                 1
```

coming from:

```
df['Flat_level'] = df['Flat_level'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace (' parter', '0') if x != np.NaN else x == np.NaN)
df['Flat_level'] = df['Flat_level'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace (' suterena', '-1') if x != np.NaN else x == np.NaN)
df['Flat_level'] = df['Flat_level'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace (' > 10', '20') if x != np.NaN else x == np.NaN)
df['Flat_level'] = df['Flat_level'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace (' poddasze', '30') if x != np.NaN else x == np.NaN)
```

Before these previous changes:

Type:

```
type(df['Flat_level'][3])
```

> float

When trying to count NaN values:

```
df.isna().sum()
```

I get no 'NaN' values for "Flat_level" column:

```
Price_(zł)                0   
Area_(m2)                 0   
Rooms                     0   
Market                    0   
Building_type             0   
Flat_level                0   
Building_flat_levels      1249
Windows                   0   
Heating                   0   
Year_of_construction      1734
Finishing_level           0   
Property_form             0   
Construction_materials    0   
latitude                  0   
longitude                 0   
link                      0   
dtype: int64
```

Any idea why?
Thx

Comment: please paste the data directly in the question and format as code. makes it easier to copy

Comment: is the entry a string? ```type(df['Flat_level'][3])```

Comment: I have edited the question. Before changing words for numbers, the type of that field was float.

Comment: Its not reproducible. I am getting `1` Nan for `Flat_Level`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better use the numpy function `np.isnan()` instead of native Python to know if the value is nan. You also need to update the end of your `apply()` method otherwise you will have only boolean in your dataframe instead of nan values. You can do something like this :

```
df['Flat_level'] = df['Flat_level'].apply(
    lambda x: str(x).replace (' parter', '0') if (type(x) == float and not np.isnan(x)) or type(x)!=float else np.NaN
)
```

Comment: Like this I get this error: "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: It is because you have strings in the column "Flat_level". I updated the code to take this into account